# Cannot make Jersey 2.x hook the CORS filter

Tags: java, jersey, cors

I need to enable the CORS headers on jersey server side because otherwise the Angualr frontend is getting:

```
        XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/api/products. 
    No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. 
Origin 'http://localhost:9000' is therefore not allowed access.
```

As [Jersey documentation explained](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/filters-and-interceptors.html#d0e9711) I set up the filter and made it discoverable using `web.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
            <param-value>ny.devtest.endtoend.config.ApplicationConfig</param-value>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequestFilters</param-name>

            <param-name>ny.devtest.endtoend</param-name>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

The filter interceptior implementation:

```
package ny.devtest.endtoend;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestContext;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerResponseContext;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerResponseFilter;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;
import java.io.IOException;

@Provider
public class ResponseCorsFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter {

    public ResponseCorsFilter() {
        System.out.println("ServerResponseFilter initialization");
    }

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext containerRequestContext, ContainerResponseContext containerResponseContext) throws IOException {


        containerResponseContext.getHeaders().add("X-Powered-By", "Jersey :-)");
        containerResponseContext.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        containerResponseContext.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, OPTIONS");

    }
}
```

It is not working.

UPDATE:

```
package ny.devtest.endtoend.config;

import ny.devtest.endtoend.api.OrderResource;
import org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.BeanValidationMode;
import org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.MarshallerProperties;
import org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.binding.AbstractBinder;
import org.glassfish.jersey.jackson.JacksonFeature;
import org.glassfish.jersey.moxy.json.MoxyJsonConfig;
import org.glassfish.jersey.moxy.json.MoxyJsonFeature;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerProperties;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.validation.ValidationConfig;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.validation.internal.InjectingConstraintValidatorFactory;

import javax.validation.ParameterNameProvider;
import javax.validation.Validation;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestContext;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerResponseContext;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ResourceContext;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.ContextResolver;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class ApplicationConfig  extends ResourceConfig {

    private void ApplicationInit(){
        // Resources.
        packages(OrderResource.class.getPackage().getName());

        // Validation.
        property(ServerProperties.BV_SEND_ERROR_IN_RESPONSE, true);
        property(ServerProperties.BV_DISABLE_VALIDATE_ON_EXECUTABLE_OVERRIDE_CHECK, true);

        // Providers - JSON.
        register(JacksonFeature.class);
        register(MoxyJsonFeature.class);
        register(new MoxyJsonConfig().setFormattedOutput(true)
                .property(MarshallerProperties.BEAN_VALIDATION_MODE, BeanValidationMode.NONE)
                .resolver());

    }
    public ApplicationConfig() {
        ApplicationInit();
        // Bindings (@Inject)
        register(new ApplicationBinder());
    }
    public ApplicationConfig(AbstractBinder customBinder) {
        ApplicationInit();
        register(customBinder);
    }

    @Override // << NOT WORKING
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext containerRequestContext, ContainerResponseContext containerResponseContext) throws IOException {
        containerResponseContext.getHeaders().add("X-Powered-By", "Jersey :-)");
        containerResponseContext.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        containerResponseContext.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, OPTIONS");

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try it:

```
package ny.devtest.endtoend.config;

import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;
import ...

public class ApplicationConfig  extends ResourceConfig {

    private void ApplicationInit(){
        // Resources.
        packages(OrderResource.class.getPackage().getName());

        // Register CORS filter.
        register(ny.devtest.endtoend.ResponseCorsFilter.class);

        // Register the rest you need
        ...

    }

     public ApplicationConfig() {
        ApplicationInit();
        // Bindings (@Inject)
        register(new ApplicationBinder());
    }
   ...
}
```

And configure in `web.xml` like that

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
            <param-value>ny.devtest.endtoend.config.ApplicationConfig</param-value>
        </init-param>

        <!-- Add parameter for CORS filter -->
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>
               ny.devtest.endtoend
            </param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: invalid syntax. Second `<init-param>`

Comment: Sorry, I missed close tag for `<init-param>`

Answer (score 1):

There are a few options to configure this

1. The way you are *trying* to do (in the web.xml). With this, you are 1) specifying the wrong init-param name. It should be `jersey.config.server.provider.classnames` and 2) You need to specify the (fully qualified) *name* of the filter class as the init-param value, not the package.
2. You have a java configuration class (`ApplicationConfig`), so you can just register the filter there
3. If you are using package (or classpath) scanning it should automatically pick up the filter and register it, because of the `@Provider` annotation.

For help with 2 or 3, please show your `ApplicationConfig` class. I'm not sure if you are directly subclassing `Application` or `ResourceConfig`. They are different in how they are configured.